# Why this Java Code is compiling successfully

Tags: java, compilation, equals, hashcode

I haven't overridden much of **hashCode()** and **equals()** methods so I may be wrong
My question is for the last line where

`dep1.equals(emp2)` is being compiled successfully(why) (I am expecting compilation error as they have different types) and after compiling I get following

```
15   15    false
```

where I am expecting **15   15   true** since I am checking the hashcode in the equals method.

```
class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Employee(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id; 
    }

    public boolean equals(Employee employee) {
        return this.hashCode() == employee.hashCode();
    }


    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

class Department {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Department(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id; 
    }

    public boolean equals(Department department) {
        return this.hashCode() == department.hashCode();
    }


    public int getDepartmentId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}


public class JavaCollections {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Second Employee", 15);

        Department dep1 = new Department("Department One", 15);

        System.out.println(dep1.hashCode()+"  "+emp2.hashCode()+"  " + dep1.equals(emp2));
    }
}
```

Comment: `I haven't overridden much of hashCode() and equals()`, exactly, actually you didn´t override `Object#equals` as you did just overload it. Overriding it would have required the method to look like `public boolean equals(Object)`.

Comment: You didn't override `equals(Object obj)`,  the parameters are part of a method's signature. Also consider adding the `@Override` annotation, this will avoid this type of mistakes .

Comment: And therefore you didn't get a compiler error, because the method being called is `equals(Object o)`; legal to the compiler, but will give a runtime exception since the implementation of that expects another Department object.

Comment: This is a good question. If you come from the C++ world, this is one of the nastiest parts of Java.

Comment: @Bathsheba Nastiest parts? You mean research `equals` and find out that there is a `equals(Object)` method? Doesn't sound hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for the reason why this compiles: all classes in Java inherit from [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), which defines [`equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method, and provides a default implementation. This is the method that you call when you compare an `Employee` and a `Department`, not one of the *overloads* that you have provided.

Your `equals` code compiles fine, because the compiler does not know that you thought you were overriding `equals` when you actually didn't. The compiler thinks that you want to make a new method

```
public boolean equals(Department department)
```

to compare `Department` objects to other `Department` objects.

If you are writing a code that overrides a method of a superclass, add `@Override` annotation to it, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Department department)
```

Now the compiler will correctly complain to you that your method does not in fact override a method in its base class, alerting you to the problem at compile time.

To fix your code change the signatures of `equals` to take `Object`, add `@Override`, check for `null` and for the correct type, do the cast, and then do the actual comparison:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Department obj) {
    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Department)) {
        return false;
    }
    Department dept = (Department)obj
    return dept.id == id;
}
```

**Note:** Implementing `equals` like this

```
return this.hashCode() == department.hashCode();
```

is very fragile. Although it works in your case, when hash code is a unique ID of the object, this wouldn't survive a code refactoring when `hashCode` is replaced with some other implementation, for example, an implementation that considers both `id` and `name`. If you want to rely on comparing IDs, compare IDs directly, without calling `hashCode` to get them.

Answer (score 1):

That's because both of classes `Employee` and `Department` still have not overriden methods `public boolean equals(Object obj)` inherited from `Object`  class.

Exactly this method is invoked in `dep1.equals(emp2)`, not `public boolean equals(Department department)`.

More specifically, read [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method mC declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method mA declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>   ...
>   **The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of mA.**

In this case `boolean equals(Department department)` **is not** subsignature of `boolean equals(Object obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, this code dep1.equals(emp2) calls default implementation of Object class.

Second, U didnt overrides the default implementation in both of your class becoz u cant override equal method for specific customizied types.

If u need ur answer to be 15 15 true

replace

```
public boolean equals(Department department) {
        return this.hashCode() == department.hashCode();
    }
```

by

```
@override
public boolean equals(Object department) {
        return this.hashCode() == department.hashCode();
    }
```